# GStreamer. How to share v4l2src?

Tags: c++, gstreamer, webcam, multimedia

I didn't know that using one webcam with multiple programs at the same time was a problem.

My program has two components that use v4l2src:

1. Preview yourself;
2. Sending to `udpsink`.

I hoped to achieve this with appsrc/appsink:

- Create a common webcam component that inside has a pipeline:
  `v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! appsink`,
  and has a method `setupAppSrc` for other components that need to use it.
- `PreviewSelf` has a pipeline:
  `appsrc ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`.
- `VideoSender` has a pipeline:
  `appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! application/x-rtp, media=video, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! udpsink`.

`appsink` has a signal `new-sample`. Let's connect to it, receive the data using `gst_app_sink_pull_sample` and send it to the installed `GstAppSrc` using `gst_app_src_push_sample`.

Possible create multiple `PreviewSelf` and they will work well. But as soon as I add a `VideoSender`, everything freezes.

I tried to do:
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! tee name=mux \`
`mux. ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink \`
`mux. ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! fakesink`
And It freezes too.

Tell me, please, how several components can use a webcam?

Answer (score 0):

Your queues are too small for your `tee` pipeline. Increase them or use `tune=zerolatency` for the `x264enc` element.

Comment: Thanks, tune=zerolatency is helped. Can you tell me what do you mean "Increase them"?

Comment: I tried adding zerolatency to appsrc/appsink because it's more convenient for me.
`v4l2src ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! appsink drop=true max-lateness={ 10 * GST_MSECOND }`
`appsrc block=true is-live=true duration={ 10 * GST_MSECOND } ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`
`appsrc block=true is-live=true duration={ 10 * GST_MSECOND } ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=2 tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! ... ! udpsink port=5000`
The preview shows for a while, then everything freezes. Udpsrc pipeline does not start and remains in ready mode.